# IBM DB2: Using MINUS to exclude information in the subselect statement

Tags: sql, db2

Currently I am having an issue bringing back the correct data for this particular query below.  I am attempting to bring back data that excludes select criteria from the subselect statement after MINUS keyword.

```
SELECT
DISTINCT ORDER.OWNER, ORDER_H.PO_ID
FROM ORDER ORDER
WHERE ORDER.TYPE != 'X'
AND ORDER.STATUS='10'
AND ORDER.CLOSE_DATE IS NULL MINUS
(
   SELECT
   DISTINCT ORDER.OWNER, ORDER.PO_ID
   FROM ORDER ORDER
   INNER JOIN COST COST ON COST.PO_ID = ORDER.PO_ID
   AND COST.CODE IN
   (
      'LGSF',
      'DFCDC',
      'BOF',
      'TFR',
      'RFR',
      'TFLHC',
      'BF',
      'CBF',
      'CHAP',
      'DYPH' ,
      'OFFP',
      'PTWT',
      'DTEN',
      'OTHR',
      'DMSG',
      'STOR',
      'TOF',
      'ANTCV',
      'ANTIP',
      'CVD',
      'TRAN'
   )
   WHERE ORDER.TYPE != 'OTR'
   AND ORDER.STATUS = '10'
   AND (COST.E_AMT > 0 AND COST.A_AMT IS NULL)
)
FOR READ ONLY WITH UR
```

The data coming back includes the data within the subquery instead of excluding this data from the resultset.  I cannot figure out why this is the case.  Does anyone have any idea why after MINUS it doesn't exclude this data and is bringing back data where COST.E_AMT is actually greater than 0 and COST.A_AMT is actually populated for each CODE listed in the subquery?  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid SQL statement: in the first subselect you reference `ORDER_H.PO_ID`, but `ORDER_H` is not present in the `FROM` clause. In any case, the second subselect has `ORDER.PROFOMA_PO` instead of `PO_ID`, so clearly nothing in the second subselect can exist in the first.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, included wrong version of the query I intended to put up.  It has been edited and the sql will run, problem is that it's bring back data in the subselect query instead of removing it from the resultset.

Comment: What version of DB2? Have you looked into EXPLAIN or tried a COUNT on the outer and the inner query?

Comment: Side note: you should be using `EXCEPT` (the standard) instead of `MINUS`.  Since these are set operations, you also shouldn't need the `DISTINCT` operation (inherent in the definition), although the optimizer is probably smart enough to ignore a duplicated operation.